# How to make a variable true or false in the "if" function in pine editor?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

A very big problem I encountered when trading strategy in tradingview that I could not combine the two strategies. For example, I need a variable to be true whenever the price goes up in the Bollinger Band so that I can use it in the future. If anyone knows the solution to this problem, I will be happy to use his experiences.

```
if crossover(x > y)
    test = true
if test
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="Short")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a mutable variable and initialize it in the global scope first:
Note that `crossover` function accept arguments separated with comma.

```
var bool test = false
if crossover(x, y)
    test := true
if test
    ...
```

or

```
bool test = crossover(x, y) ? true : false
if test
    ...
```